# Median replace, needs numeric data

Tags: r, na, median, imputation

I am trying to impute missing values based on a group. I am getting an error that the median() function requires numeric data, but all of my data is numeric so I can't see the issue. Here is a minimally reproducible example.

```
set.seed(123)
cluster = sample(seq(1,10),1000,replace=TRUE)
V1 = sample(c(runif(100),NA),1000,replace=TRUE)
V2 = sample(c(runif(100),NA),1000,replace=TRUE)

df = as.data.frame(cbind(cluster,V1,V2))

df_fixed = by(df,df$cluster,function(x){replace(x,is.na(x),median(x, na.rm=TRUE))})
```

**Error returned:**

> Error in median.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) : need numeric data

This code will work though, so the issue is with the median function.

```
df_fixed = by(df,df$cluster,function(x){replace(x,is.na(x),1)})
```

Comment: please use `set.seed` when using functions such as `runif`, `sample` etc. to make it reproducible

Comment: `by` is cutting df into small data.frames - which are not class numeric. Are you wanting to replace with column-wise medians or an overall median?

Comment: I'm trying to replace column wise median for each by group. So if in group 1 and missing, replace with median of group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_fixed <- apply(df[,2:3], 2, function(x) {
  md <- sapply(sort(unique(df$cluster)), function(k) median(x[df$cluster==k], na.rm=TRUE)) 
  x[is.na(x)] <- md[df$cluster][is.na(x)]
  return(x)
})  

any(is.na(df_fixed))
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This code works when there is missing values in all groups. For some reason in my actual data when there are groups with no missing values, nothing gets replaced. It just skips these columns. I can't reproduce this with the dummy data so I'll have to think of a solution unless you have any ideas?

Comment: @user137698 I changed my code. Now it works also on columns that have no missing values. Try and let me know.